# merge(update) same objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

currently I am implementing a prototype of a item-list and a shopping-cart. Both components are "standalone" components and are connected via a vuex-store.
The item-list has different elements which I can add into my shopping-cart with different quantities. By adding an item, the item will be pushed as an object with some information (id, name, quantity etc.) into an array, called "products". This object will than be rendered inside of the shopping-cart.
The main problem now is, if I add one element with a quantity of "1" into the shopping-cart, everything works great, but if I now want to add the same element with a quantity of "4", this will be "correctly" added into the shopping-cart, but because it is the same element than the one before, I just want to update the quantity and therefore of course the price of the first element. So when I add an element into my shopping-cart, there has to be a check, which makes sure, that if there is the same element (maybe based on the id) it will merge the same objects. I hope my question is clear :D

My function for adding the element to the array is the following:

```
addToBasket(key) {
          if (this.products[key].qty >= 1) {
            this.$store.commit('addProduct', {
              id: this.products[key].product_id,
              title: this.products[key].title,
              price: {
                value: this.products[key].price.value,
                currency: this.products[key].price.currency,
              },
              qty: this.products[key].qty
            });
          }
        }
```

and the corresponding mutation from the store is this:

```
addProduct(state, payload) {
    state.products.push(payload);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are storing data in `key: value` pairs Key will be item name and value will be the quantity in that case.

Before you push new entry, check the variable containing stored data whether a key in your case 'state' is already present. If present update value ('payload') alone. Else push both state and payload.

```
if ("key" in myObj)
{
    //Code to update payload
}
else
{
    //Code to insert key and value pair
}
```

[More info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-a-key-exists-in-javascript-object/#:~:text=There%20are%20mainly%20two%20methods,property%20is%20in%20the%20object.)

or try this way

```
function keyExists(key, search) {
        if (!search || (search.constructor !== Array && search.constructor !== Object)) {
            return false;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
            if (search[i] === key) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return key in search;
    }

// How to use it:
// Searching for keys in Arrays
console.log(keyExists('apple', ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'])); // true
console.log(keyExists('fruit', ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'])); // false

// Searching for keys in Objects
console.log(keyExists('age', {'name': 'Bill', 'age': 29 })); // true
console.log(keyExists('title', {'name': 'Jason', 'age': 29 })); // false
```

Optimized way to do the checking

```
yourObjName.hasOwnProperty(key) : 
{
//Code to add payload alone 
}
? 
{
//Code to push state and payload;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I had a lot of work in the last days.
I am sorry, but I dont really get your point :/
My array consists of different objects. I have a method, which merges the objects, but I dont really know, where I have to put this, so update the data in the store.